# Track screen timeouts

Tags: windows-7, mac, security, lock-screen

I would like to build a script to send an email (or write to a network share .csv) everytime a computer goes to sleep after 15 minutes of inactivity (Screen saver).

The goal is to track which employees are not locking their screens when leaving their desk for meetings or lunch.

This would be deployed for a mixed Mac/PC environment.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but what's the question to us?  Please note: we're not a script writing service.

Comment: we would like to see what have your tried or what problem are you facing

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Not here to write a script.  However I can provide a resource which may benefit in writing one for your PC's that may be running Windows. You should be able to capture these particular events within the windows security event logs by looking for the following EventID's, these events are also timestamped as they are written which may help in other calculations related to time.

- 4802: The screen saver was invoked
- 4803: screensaver dismissed
- 4800: console locked
- 4801: console unlocked

Its possible to create a task scheduler task to monitor these events as well within Windows to potentially invoke an action method to write to a csv / send an email / etc depending on the triggered task type that you use.

https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4802